# How can I buy Canonical Ubuntu Advantage licence for Ubuntu OS installed on one of cloud VM and how can I apply that licence

Tags: cloud, canonical, license, ubuntu-advantage

I have Ubuntu installed in a cloud VM,how can I buy Canonical's Ubuntu Advantage service? Can I buy it and apply it to Ubuntu install on my cloud VM? Will this license provide me any Ubuntu Bug Support and upgrades?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canonical Ubuntu Advantage License is for businesses not for personal usage.

> Will this license provide me any Ubuntu Bug Support and upgrades.

Yes. It may provide you a custom patch if you encounter a bug, but in general Ubuntu updates are available free of charge - unlike SUSE or RHEL's.

Website for **[Ubuntu Advantage](http://www.ubuntu.com/management/ubuntu-advantage)** .

- It includes access to Landscape, the systems management tool.
- Exclusive to Ubuntu Advantage subscribers, the Canonical Knowledge Base is an online library of articles on technical issues including security, migration and networking.
- Canonical’s Global Support & Services team provides around-the-clock coverage for Ubuntu deployments all over the world. Telephone support gives you access to engineers with first-hand experience of your issues, while the online portal lets you track the progress of cases in real time.

There are 3 levels: [desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/management), [server](http://www.ubuntu.com/server/management) and [cloud](http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/management) management.

---

Form to [**Contact Canonical**](http://www.ubuntu.com/management/contact-us)

> Considering Ubuntu for your business? Just fill in the form below and a member of our team will be in touch within two working days.

Comment: Yes we need it for business purpose only, so if we buy it how can we apply it to our currently installed Ubuntu OS and can we use same license for provisioning more than one VM.

Comment: I would fill out the form and have them call you ;)